# Jsf 2.2 not working with html5

Tags: html, managed-bean, jsf-2.2

jsf 2.2 tags are not working with html5. It is working perfectly with .xhtml .

html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
    xmlns:p="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<input type="text" jsf:id="input1" jsf:value="#{Sample.name}" />

  <h:inputText value="#{Sample.name}" >
            <f:passThroughAttribute name="placeholder" value="Enter text" />
        </h:outputText>
</body>
</html>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
  <display-name>sample-war</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
  </listener>
</web-app>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
    version="2.2">
<managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>Sample</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.sample.SampleBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
</faces-config>
```

Managed beans are present in the core module , webapp contents in war . I am packaging poth in a ear and trying to deploy it onto glassfish.
Any answer would be of great help.

Comment: Let me guess: your "html page" has file extension `.html`? B/c your Faces Servlet isn't configured to process these files. And it shouldn't. Facelets are XHTML, as defined by the standard. The *output* may be valid HTML5.

Comment: i am trying to implement jsf2.2 with html5. my requirement is to reneder jsf tags in html5.even though jsf2.2 is said to be supported in html5 ,its not working for me . http://www.infoq.com/news/2013/06/jsf22-html5

Comment: It's the other way around: you can now produce HTML5 with JSF-2.2 (which wasn't possible before since JSF stripped your "non-HTML" attributes). While it's possible to have your xhtml files named `*.html`, you need to tell JSF you did that by including the appropiate `servlet-mapping`.

Comment: Replace `<head>` with `<h:head/>`

Comment: <h:head> also doesnt work .

Comment: in jsf you have to use xhtml, you can't use html. all jsf tags won't work. also, you are not supposed to use <input/>, use one of jsf inputs instead. you have to use h:head and h:body.
you don't need to declare managed beans in faces-config, that was required only in jsf 1. use annotations instead (@ManagedBean, @SessionScoped)

Comment: @Damian you didn't considered the changes in jsf 2.2.